# Dynamic Hyperlink via Calculated Columns Truncating at Space

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to generate a hyperlink to an item page using a calculated column. I'm 99% of the way there, but I run into issues when the title has spaces.

My calculated column has the following formula:

```
=CONCATENATE(
  "<a href=https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Content%20Type.aspx?ContentType="
  ,[Title]
  ,">"
  ,Title
  ,"</a>"
)
```

The problem is in the first reference of `Title`. With our without brackets, if the title has a space, the title stops after the first word and fails to point to the correct page.

e.g.

Title = `First Item`
Calculated Column Result = `https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Content%20Type.aspx?ContentType=First`
Desired Result = `https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Content%20Type.aspx?ContentType=First%20Item`

Is there any way I can do this via calculated column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you put the href in single quotes, anything displaying it will auto change the space to the correct %20. Just before the https, and just before the > at the end of the href.

```
=CONCATENATE(
  "<a href='https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Content%20Type.aspx?ContentType="
  ,[Title]
  ,"'>"
  ,Title
  ,"</a>")
```

Comment: Simple solution and worked beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the **Browser adds " quotes** around the HREF tag
it adds a closing quote **at the first space** it finds in the string

You can enter those quotes yourself with escape notation;
two quotes: **""** will output one quote *"* in the string

String concatenation can also be done with **&**

So your Formula becomes:

```
="<a href=""https://oursite.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename/SitePages/Content%20Type.aspx?ContentType="
  &Title
  &""">"
  &Title
  &"</a>"
```

The single quote mentioned in the other answer also works,
because the Browser will replace it with a double-quote.

Using the escape **""** notation allows the single quote **'** to be used for quoting URL string parameters
(like ContentType='string' if required) or in JavaScript code additions

So you can do: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How
*Be sure to read the Pros & Cons of using HTML/JavaScript in Calculated Columns*